# F# for C#/Haskell programmer

Tags: c#, .net, haskell, f#

What is recommended tutorial of F# for Haskell programmer? F# seems to borrow a lot from Haskell but there are little traps which makes hard to write.

Generally I need walkthrough the F# which would not explain what is the difference between mutable data and immutable (Haskell is much more strict in this area) etc.

I know C# a little so I know more or less what .Net is about as well.

Comment: You've got your history wrong. F# borrows a lot from ML, from which Haskell also borrows a lot. Saying that F# borrows from Haskell is like saying that Java was inspired by C#.

Comment: Pascal: F# is mostly based on ML, but borrows other pieces from Haskell (which isn't a surprise since some people worked on both).

Comment: http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Dr-Don-Syme-Introduction-to-F-1-of-3/

Comment: @Pascal: The stuff in F# may have originated in ML but it certainly came via Haskell due to the enormously Haskell-centric MS. The few features that F# takes directly from OCaml have an alien feel. For example, statically typing `printf` but failing to optimize it; using OCaml syntax but replacing professional tools like autoindenting with a Haskell-style `#light` syntax designed for GUI-challenged displays; F# had only Haskell-style pattern matching for many years and no advanced features like or-patterns from MLs; weak inference like Haskell with none of the structural typing OCaml enjoys.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since you will already know 90% of the concepts, I would just focus on the syntax, and read e.g. the [F# Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233181.aspx) on an as-needed basis.  Pick a few basic tasks for yourself, try to code them up, use the reference to get un-stuck, and ask questions here when you get really stuck.

(You won't find many docs aimed at you, since the "I know Haskell, but not ML or F#" set of people is much much smaller than the "I know C#, but not Haskell, ML, or F#" group.)

(You might also consider picking and choosing from [my blog](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/?_c11_BlogPart_BlogPart=summary&_c=BlogPart); I write both beginner stuff and advanced stuff.)

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit afraid of reading language reference but as far it was most valuable resource written in very good style.

Answer (score 7):

Free:

[The F# Survival Guide](http://www.ctocorner.com/fsharp/book/default.aspx)

[F# Wiki Book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming)

Good books:

[Programming F#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596153643) for beginners

[Expert F#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590598504) for those who already write simple F# programs

Comment: I'm not saying that they are bad books/sources but they have kind of different approach. I not a person who thinks in terms of `for` loops but someone who needs to know how to rewrite `intercalate "." . map show` into F# (problem which was mentioned by Brian).